# trying the IBM i CPYSPLF to *TOSTMF for the first time?

Tags: ibm-midrange

I am trying the CPYSPLF to *TOSTMF for the first time.

I looks very promising, except when I view file on IFS using iSeries navigator editor it looks like EPSIDIC crap. though it looks ok using wrklnk.  Where can I convert to ASCII or useful CCSID?

```
> QSYS/CPYSPLF FILE(QPJOBLOG) TOFILE(*TOSTMF) 
> JOB(123980/USER99/USER99_1) SPLNBR(*LAST)     
> TOSTMF('/tmp/USER99.txt') STMFOPT(*REPLACE)
```

Crap:

```
@õ÷÷ðââñ@å÷ÙòÔð@ñôðôñø@@@@@@@@@
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@Ñ–‚@Ó–‡@@@@@
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@×Ö
âÄÅå@@@@ðóañôañø@@ñõzðøzó÷@ÃÄã@@
```

Info on IFS files:

```
Owner  . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . :   HAPPYUSER     
System object is on  . . . . . . . . . :   Local        
Auxiliary storage pool . . . . . . . . :   1            
  Object overflowed  . . . . . . . . . :   No           

Coded character set ID . . . . . . . . :   37      <<<     
Hidden file  . . . . . . . . . . . . . :   No           
PC system file . . . . . . . . . . . . :   No           
Read only  . . . . . . . . . . . . . . :   No           

Need to archive (PC) . . . . . . . . . :   Yes          
Need to archive (System) . . . . . . . :   Yes
```

thanks!

Comment: From WRKLNK, "8=Display attributes" shows what as a CCSID?

Comment: WRKLNK, "8=Display attributes" shows  ICCSID 37,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your stream file is in EBCDIC, and I don't see a way to adjust the CCSID using `CPYSPLF`. But you could use CPYSPLF to a physical file member, and then use `CPYTOSTMF` to copy the data to the IFS with conversion to a useful ASCII CCSID.

Answer (score 1):

It's conceivable that IBM will eventually upgrade the `CPYSPLF` command to allow specification of the destination CCSID, but until then, the most straightforward thing to do is convert the stream file after the fact.

The simplest way I've found to do that is the `CPY` command:

```
CPY &STMF TOOBJ(&STMF) TOCCSID(&CCSID) DTAFMT(*TEXT) REPLACE(*YES)
```

Note that you can specify the same stream file as both the source and the destination to overwrite the original with the converted data.

Comment: This did the trick:

CPY OBJ('/tmp/file1.txt')                             
TOOBJ('/tmp/file2.txt') TOCCSID(819) DTAFMT(*TEXT)

Answer (score 1):

You can configure iNav to automatically convert files with a given extension...

From the Help...

> **Set up file text conversion**
>   To set file text conversion, follow these
>   steps:
>
> 1. In the System i Navigator window, expand the system you want to use.
> 2. Expand File Systems.
> 3. Right-click Integrated File System and select Properties.
> 4. Enter the file extension that you want to convert
>      automatically in the File extensions for automatic text file
>      conversion text box and click Add.
> 5. Repeat step 4 for all file
>      extensions that you want to convert automatically.
> 6. Click OK.

Interestingly, the IFS tooling in the iNav replacement, Access Client Solutions (ACS) doesn't appear to have the same option..

Answer (score 1):

cpysplf to a file in the correct format.

```
pseudo code
delete user99.txt
copy knowngood.txt   user99.txt
cpysplf /user99.txt
```